# GSub removing all characters before first digit

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm using R to clean some very dirty addresses.  I'd like to remove all characters preceding the FIRST number in the string using gsub, but can's seem to figure out a regular expression that works.  Any suggestions?

Here are three examples of the data:

C/O Bob Jones1071 Main St

PLEASE ADDRESS VERIFY64 Center Road

Joe's Bakery33 Pleasant Ave #4

Comment: You won't find one that covers all as addresses don't follow format. You can try `^\D+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(V2 = str_extract_all(V1, "\\d+.*"))
#                             V1                 V2
# 1           C/O Bob Jones1071 Main St       1071 Main St
# 2 PLEASE ADDRESS VERIFY64 Center Road     64 Center Road
# 3       Joes Bakery33 Pleasant Ave #4 33 Pleasant Ave #4
```

Data

```
structure(list(V1 = c("C/O Bob Jones1071 Main St", "PLEASE ADDRESS VERIFY64 Center Road", 
"Joes Bakery33 Pleasant Ave #4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```